# Append items to a list in a for loop using an immutable list?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

```
val list = List()
for(i <- 1 to 10){
    list:+i
}
println(list)
```

This ends up giving me an empty list although it should be filled with numbers from 1 to 10? I have a theory that it creates a new list each time due to the ":" operator but I am not entirely sure. I have solved the issue using a ListBuffer instead but I want to learn how to approach such a problem using immutable lists instead. Thank you.

Comment: `val list = (1 to 10).toList` or `val list = List.range(1,11)`

Comment: @jwvh I understand this approach for simple lists but what about if I was using a for each loop where the elements weren't simple integers but a unique set of strings? How would I then append those strings to an immutable list?

Comment: _"append ... to an immutable"_ i.e. change an unchangeable. You don't. When you want to add an element to a fixed collection you have to create a new collection with all the desired elements: `val newlist = 0 :: oldlist`

Comment: `immutable` is means something which stays un-changed-forever. If you can change something, then it simply would not be immutable. This is similar to looking for a prime number which is divisible by 2, 3 and 4.

Comment: "I want to learn how to approach such a problem using immutable lists instead" – You can't change an immutable list. That is literally what the word "immutable" means: "mutable" derives from Latin and means "changeable", "im-" is a prefix which negates the word being prefixed, ergo, "immutable", *literally* means "non-changeable".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no single functional solution to this class of problem, but here are some options.

For the simple case in the question, you can do this

```
List.range(1,11) // List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

If you want to calculate a different value for each element based on index, use `tabulate`:

```
List.tabulate(10)(x => x*3) // List(0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27)
```

(You can pass a function if the logic is more complicated than this)

If you are building a list but are not sure whether you need every element, use `Option` and then `flatten`:

```
def genValue(i: Int): Option[Int] = ???

List.tabulate(10)(genValue).flatten
```

This will discard any values where `genValue` returns `None` and extract the `Int` where it returns `Some(???)`.

If each operation may return a different number of elements, use `List` then `flatten`:

```
def genValue(i: Int): List[Int] = ???

List.tabulate(10)(genValue).flatten
```

This will take all the elements from all the `List` values returned by `genValue` and put them into a single `List[Int]`.

If the length of the `List` is not known in advance then the best solution is likely to be a recursive function. While this may seem daunting to start with, it is worth learning how to use them as they are often the cleanest way of solving a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add an element (that is mutate the list) to an immutable list.
You are right when you say:

> I have a theory that it creates a new list each time

as a first step consider

```scala
      var list = List.empty[Int]
      
      for(i <- 1 to 10) {
        list = list :+ i
      }

      println(list)
```

note that list is now a **var**iable so that we can reassign value, but *the list* is still an immutable object. Infact for each iteratin we reassign to the variable list a ***new*** list with an element appended
If you don't like the use of a variable you could use a fold operation, which is not much different from the for above, it still construct partial lists adding element one by one

```scala
      val result = (1 to 10).foldLeft(List.empty[Int]){ (partial_list, item) =>
        partial_list :+ item
      }
      
      println(result)
```

Comment: Please don't give answers that use `var`, there are plenty of functional solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplified signature of `:+`:

```scala
def :+(elem: B): List[B]
```

It returns a new List with `elem` so it does not alter the current `list`.

To make this work switch to a `ListBuffer` i.e. something mutable:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer


val buffer = ListBuffer.empty[Int]

for(i <- 1 to 10) {
  buffer += i
}

println(buffer)
```

If you want to keep the immutable List you could accumulate with `fold`:

```scala
val list = List.empty[Int]

(1 to 10)
  .foldLeft(list) { (acc, value) =>  acc :+ value }
```